# Why Builder.add should be used for junctions but not for Source/Flow/Sink in GraphDSL.create?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

In `akka-stream` [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.5/scala/stream/stream-graphs.html) there is an example on how to use `GraphDSL.create` for constructing graphs of nonlinear shapes. The simplest code sample follows for a graph with one fan-out element:

```
val graph = GraphDSL.create(){implicit builder =>
  val source = Source(1 to 100)
  val flow = Flow.apply[Int]
  val sink1 = Sink.foreach[Int](println)
  val sink2 = Sink.foreach[Int](i => println("Sink2: " + i))
  val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
  source ~> flow ~> broadcast.in
  broadcast.out(0) ~> sink1
  broadcast.out(1) ~> sink2
  ClosedShape
}
RunnableGraph.fromGraph(graph).run()
```

My question is why instance of `Broadcast` should be 'imported' with help of `builder.add` method while for source/sink/flow a regular instantiation is enough?

If I remove `builder.add` and just leave the `val broadcast = Broadcast[Int](2)` then the code will compile but at runtime an exception will be thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Broadcast.in] is already connected
```

Documentation does not explain this clearly and just provides it as something given.
Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GraphDSL allows you to build a graph with a series of stateful operations, for this reason **all** the stages of your graph **must** be added to the builder. The `builder.add` operation returns the `Shape` of a stage, which is basically its blueprint. The `Shape` can be used with the `~>` combinators to compose your graph.

Some types of stages, however, are more used than others (namely, `Source`, `Sink`, `Flow`), so for these stages Akka provides conveniency functions that add them to the builder for you as part of the `~>` call.

Take a look at the differences between [this function](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Graph.scala#L1342) and [this function](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Graph.scala#L1339) in the Akka source code to better understand. These are the `~>` functions for `Sink`s.

Comment: I see. They have specific implementations of the operator for this cases where they add to builder and extract the shape. Thanks.